# Auth::check() return false after refresh or redirect page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

here is my Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
    Route::get('/play/{game_id}', 'PlayController@play');
});
```

here is my kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

Here is my play method that i am checking Authentication if not Login yet, it will create or fetch user from database and call Auth::login()

```
public function play($game_id)
    {
        $this->game_id_ = $game_id;

        if(!Auth::check())
        {
            echo "Not login yet.";
            $user = "username";
            $name = "password";
            $id = "1234555";
            $email = "email@email.com";
            $avatar = "pic.png";
            // echo $avatar;
            (new SocialAuthController)->facebookLoginAndUpdateData($name, $id, $email, $avatar);
        }
    }
```

It's calling Auth::login($user, true) in facebookLoginAndUpdateData()

```
public function facebookLoginAndUpdateData($name, $email, $facebook_id, $avatar)
    {
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($name, $email, $facebook_id, $avatar);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return $authUser;
    }

    private function findOrCreateUser($name, $email, $facebook_id, $avatar)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('facebook_id', $facebook_id)->first();

        if ($authUser){
            return $authUser;
    }

    return User::create([
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'facebook_id' => $facebook_id,
        'avatar' => $avatar
    ]);
  }
```

The problem is, 
for first time that call play() it create new row in database.

After that , i have refresh this page but Auth::check() still return false although i have call Auth::login($user ,true) on first time,

It should remember that i already logged in and Auth::check() should return true, 
I have google it for 4 hours but i still can't fix it.

Anyone have the same problem, please help . Thank you.

Comment: What session driver are you planning on using? If you have not set your session driver then you may find that a session is lost on page refresh or redirection.

You may also find this helpful if you are trying authentication using social media 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#social-authentication

Comment: @Spholt I want to implement manual authentication without Socialite. And how to set driver session to maintain the session.

Comment: The session driver can be set in the `.env` file as `SESSION_DRIVER` or ,if you aren't using dotenv, in `/config/session.php`. Documentation on laravel session drivers and how they are used can be found here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)

Answer (score 0):

check `if (Auth::guest()) {}` instead of `if(!Auth::check()){}`

Comment: I think it not a point , because if i already logged in , it should return true for Auth::check().